# Point Nginx subdomains at specific directory

Tags: mod-rewrite, nginx, dns, subdomain

I configured an nginx server block. And I'm still stack on one last thing.
I want the www.domain.com to point at a specific directory (root /var/www/directory1) and all the other subdomains (e.g sub1.domain.com, etc,  execpt the www) to point at an other directory (root /var/www/directory2).
How do you do that ?
Rewrite or proxy pass?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a default server block to match all of your domains with the exception of `www.example.com`. For example:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /var/www/directory2;
    ...
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    root /var/www/directory1;
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for details.